# "E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'PWideChar'" при вызове ftpputfile()

Tags: delphi, ftp

```
program wininet_pr_test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  windows,
  wininet,
  inifiles,
  shellapi;

var

 conn_param,inet_open : hinternet;
 Ini: Tinifile;
 sip : String;
 slogin: String;
 spas: String;

procedure upload(filename:pchar; ftpfilename:pchar);

const

port=21;

begin
 Ini:=TiniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'c:\MyIni.ini');
inet_open:=internetopen('iexplore',INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,nil,nil,0);
sip:=Ini.ReadString('PSS','ip', 'default value');
slogin:=Ini.ReadString('PSS','login', 'default value');
spas:=Ini.ReadString('PSS','pass', 'default value');
sleep(100);

conn_param:=internetconnect(inet_open,sip,port,slogin,spas,INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);

ftpputfile(conn_param,filename,ftpfilename,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,0);

 internetclosehandle(conn_param);

 internetclosehandle(inet_open) ;
 end;
```

Ругается на:

```
  ftpputfile(conn_param,filename,ftpfilename,FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,0);
```

> [DCC Error] wininet_pr_test.dpr(41): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'PWideChar'

P.S. Если есть замечанию по коду, буду признателен. Я любитель)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что тут непонятного? Ты не правильные типы в процедуру кидаешь...

```
FtpPutFile(hConnect, 'ТЕКС', 'ТЕКС', FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
```

а у тебя `pchar`, а надо `string`.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но не получается сделать)

Comment: нашел ошибку: Ini := TIniFile.Create('c:\MyIni.ini');  // так правильно

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать явное приведение типов:

```
ftpputfile(conn_param, string(filename), string(ftpfilename), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, 0);
```

`sleep` нужно убрать. Для чего он вам?

```
inet_open := internetopen('iexplore', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, nil, nil, 0);

Ini := TINIFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(paramstr(0)) + 'MyIni.ini'); // будет открыт файл MyIni.ini, который лежит рядом с программой 
try
  sip := Ini.ReadString('PSS', 'ip', 'default value');
  slogin := Ini.ReadString('PSS', 'login', 'default value');
  spas := Ini.ReadString('PSS', 'pass', 'default value');
finally
  Ini.Free; // созданные объекты нужно уничтожать, когда они больше не нужны, чтобы не было утечек памяти
end;
```